# Reversed chars - foreach loop

Tags: c#

I want to print the 3 lines of characters in reversed order but this example is done simply. How can I do it with foreach loop without using arrays?

```
public static void Main()
{
    char firstInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    char secondInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    char thirdInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine(thirdInput.ToString() + " " + secondInput.ToString() + " " + firstInput.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework question, or is there some other reason for wanting to do this without using an array?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "with foreach loop without arrays"? Foreach loops by definition iterate over collections (or rather, enumerables). If you can't use an array, which collection type do you want to use?

Comment: @MatthewWatson as I mentioned I want to do this without using an array.

Comment: But what do you want to loop over in the absence of the array?!

Comment: Are you allowed to use a `List<string>`? Are you allowed to use something like Linq which may used an array or list internally without exposing it?

Comment: @MatthewWatson I still hadn't learn arrays and list that's why I want to do it without them.

Comment: In that case you already have the most optimal solution!

Comment: So it's time to do so. :)

Comment: @SPECTR4L: So you don't want to learn something because you haven't learned it?  Seems like a dead end.  Regardless, the question remains... What do you want to loop over?  Maybe if you make *some* effort to implement your idea and run into a problem then we can help with that problem.

Comment: FYI - you could use `char firstInput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;` instead of `char = firstInput = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());`

Comment: Why `foreach` loop? Why not `for` or `while` loop?

Comment: Wow this question is a grave yard

Answer (score 0):

You could create a method using the `params` keyword - not tested but something like:

```
private static string ReverseOrder(params char[] characters)
{
    var result = "";
    for (int i = characters.count; i > 0; i--)
    {
         result = result + characters[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

and call like:

```
var reverseOrderResult = ReverseOrder(firstinput, secondinput, thirdinput);
```

Comment: `params char[]` <-- `[]` indicating there's an array. Don't answer questions that can't be properly answered without clarification from the OP.

Comment: @CodeCaster it is an array, but to be fair it requires no knowledge of arrays to call

Answer (score 0):

Here's an attempt to follow the input conditions: no arrays and use of foreach loop (I'm sure the author isn't looking for something like this)

```
static void Main()
{
    var result = "";
    foreach (var c in NextInput(3))
    {
        result = c + " " + result;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

private static IEnumerable<char> NextInput(int count)
{
    var i = 0;
    while (i++ < count)
        yield return char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}
```

Comment: OP doesn't know how array works, you thing OP will be familiar with IEnumerable and yielding?...I don't think so :)

Comment: No, no :) I don't think so